# Importing global stylesheet webpack

Tags: webpack, stylus

I'm creating an app with [Angular-2-Webpack-Starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter). I'm using Stylus to style my Angular 2 Components, which is working really well.

I also want to be able to use a global sheet of pre-defined colors.

```
//colors.styl

dark-background = #000

bronze-badge = rgb(165, 103, 63)
silver-badge = rgb(156, 156, 156)
gold-badge = rgb(251, 189, 8)
enter code here
```

What is the "Webpack way" of giving all of my individual stylesheets access to this data?

Comment: You should be able to use an `@import 'colors'` statement at the beginning of another CSS file to include these.

Comment: @ordonezalex How do I pull from the root directory? These aren't all in the same folder. One file is `/src/app/components/foo.styl` and I need to import `/src/assets/colors.styl`. Can I do this without relative paths?